# get back office starter

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-starter

When I first purchased my computer office starter 2010 came preinstalled with it.I installed office professional trial which is now expired.

I want to get the starter version back - it was uninstalled with the install of the trial .

I'd like to avoid re-downloading everything in order to save bandwidth, so I'd like to get it back from the install I had before.

I found out that office starter installer is available for download from microsoft's servers but the installer downloads files from internet during the install process.what i want is an offline version of the installer how can i do that?

Comment: Why can't you use the installer?  You download the exact same amount of data.  Without restoring the factory image what you want might not be possible.

Comment: the installer is around 1 mb but it will download hundreds of MBs during install. is there a way to get all the files bfore starting the install

Comment: You download it once and look in the cache folder.  I don't think Microsoft offers an offline installer for Starter editions of Office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Google is, as always, your friend.  The trick is knowing some of the right key words.... like, in this example, **offline installer**.

Apparently, MS doesn't want to provide you with a direct download of Office Starter 2010 for offline installation.  This doesn't mean it isn't possible.

[Here's one inventive programmer, who created a little application to download and save the installation files for offline use.](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/34092-Office-2010-Starter-Offline-Setup-Tool)

[Here is an article about doing this, with links to a batch file that would need to be edited before use (since the batch file was initially written for getting the German version).](http://www.instantfundas.com/2011/11/download-free-microsoft-office-starter.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20InstantFundas%20%28Instant%20Fundas%29)

So, have at it.  Yes, I know you said you don't want to Re-download everything.  So assuming you already performed a factory recovery and Office Starter 2010 wasn't there, this is really your only option.

That, or you could switch to Open Office or Libre Office.

Comment: a good chunk of the mirrors linking to the first site seem down - might need to try them until you get one that works. It does seem to do the trick however